# Determining how many subtopics are inside of an MQTT topic

Tags: mqtt

So I am using the Mosquito MQTT broker for a project and I'm subscribing to a topic that has a variable number of subtopics. Is there any way of knowing how many subtopics a topic has without just getting the update of all the subtopics first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

Topics are ephemeral, they don't really exist except at the instant a message is published to one.

Subscribing clients supply a pattern (as it can include wildcards that match 1 or many levels of a topic `+` or `#`) and the broker matches that against the topic in the published message to decide if it should forward it to the subscriber.

The only time the broker keeps track of a topic is if it is storing a message with the retained flag set, or queuing a message for an offline client with a persistent subscription.

Comment: Thank you! That's very clear